# Get default gateway's IP address in Javascript

Tags: javascript, networking

How to get the IP address of the default gateway/router through which my computer gets connected to the internet using client-side `Javascript` ? I don't want to particularly use `Node.JS` for this purpose.

More specifically, on running Linux's `route` command, the following is the output :

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.16.0.3      0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp6s0
```

So, I need to get the IP address as `172.16.0.3` as the final result using client-side JS/HTML.

Comment: why would you need such a thing on a web page? *I don't want to particularly use Node.JS for this purpose* well, you'll need to use something on the client computer that isn't a browser!

Comment: considering **your** default gateway will never change, what's wrong with hardcoding the known value? Or are you asking how to find anybody's default gateway using a web page that is on the internet (rather than in the **intra**net

Comment: I need if for developing an App in Tizen (Samsung's OS) and nodeJS being server side can't be run on the client-side javascript supporting Tizen studio. @JaromandaX

Comment: I am doing this to perform a gateway check. @JaromandaX

Comment: I can't see any way you'll manage this in any browsers javascript engine

Comment: It doesn't need to be browser exactly. I only need client-side JS. I need to do a gateway check in a mobile app. @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var findIP = new Promise(r=>{var w=window,a=new (w.RTCPeerConnection||w.mozRTCPeerConnection||w.webkitRTCPeerConnection)({iceServers:[]}),b=()=>{};a.createDataChannel("");a.createOffer(c=>a.setLocalDescription(c,b,b),b);a.onicecandidate=c=>{try{c.candidate.candidate.match(/([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g).forEach(r)}catch(e){}}})

/*Usage example*/
findIP.then(ip => document.write('your ip: ', ip)).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Comment: This gives my computer's IP, I don't want that. I need the IP of the gateway my computer gets connected to. More, specifically, the first row of Linux's `route` command.

Comment: @Jarvis did you found a solution for that?

Comment: Also interested by a solution for this

Comment: There is an answer [here](https://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.wmi.narkive.com/pkYM6LwM/accesing-ip-address-information-using-javascript) that uses the [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WMI class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration), if you use the same code snippet including the array, I'm pretty sure you can get the "string" you're looking for from the DefaultIPGateway[] syntax, note that VBArray object is used to access the VB safeArray.

Answer (score 1):

```
h_IPaddress.Value = Convert.ToString(GetDefaultGateway());

public static IPAddress GetDefaultGateway()
{
    var gateway_address = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        .Where(e => e.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        .SelectMany(e => e.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses)
        .LastOrDefault();

    if (gateway_address == null) return null;
    return gateway_address.Address;
}
```

Comment: Welcome Christeena Sunny! Interesting answer, is this doable in Javascript?